# Visual Studio 2012 w/ Blend - where is System.Windows.Interactivity?

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend, blend-2012

I have a brand new install of VS 2012 Premium on Win8 and am trying to open an existing Silverlight project.  The project has a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll which cannot be found.  VS2012 has Blend built in but where is the SDK?  Do I need to download it from somewhere?  Should I install the Blend Ultimate trial that I had on my old VS2010 machine?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I do have to install the Blend Ultimate trial to get the SDK.  I installed it and now System.Windows.Interactivity is resolved

Comment: I've installed it and am able to revernce the v4.5 version of System.Windows.Interactivity from the Blend folder, but I can't import the namespace in my Xaml... just doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This one is an even better solution: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10801

It is the Blend SDK, which includes the System.Windows.Interactivity, and it's freely available. (it's not a trial)